# BertScore vs Cosine Similarity+Bert embeddings

Tags: bert-language-model

I am currently trying to measure relevance of x<sub>i</sub> with respect to x<sub>j</sub>. I would like to use BertScore for this. What is the difference between using the bert-score evaluator module versus using the BERT model to get contextual embeddings and then calculating cosine similairity between them?

Are the two methods mentioned here: https://haticeozbolat17.medium.com/text-summarization-how-to-calculate-bertscore-771a51022964 equivalent?